# How do I create a loop such that I get all the queries into one csv in through python?

Tags: python, pandas, api

I have created a function that fetches price, rating, etc after it hits an API:

```
def is_priced(business_id):
    try:
        priced_ind = get_business(API_KEY, business_id)
        priced_ind1 = priced_ind['price']
    except:
        priced_ind1 = 'None'
    return priced_ind1

priced_ind = is_priced(b_id)
print(priced_ind)
```

Similar for rating

```
def is_rated(business_id):

    try:
        rated_ind = get_business(API_KEY, business_id)

        rated_ind1 = rated_ind['rating']
    except:
        rated_ind1 = 'None'
    return rated_ind1
```

However, I want my function to loop through the business names I have in my CSV file and catch all this data and export it to a new csv file with these two parameters beside the names of the business.

The CSV file has info on the name of the business along with its address,city,state,zip and country

Eg:

```
Name        address             city            state zip    country
XYZ(The)    5* WE 223899th St.  New York        NY    19921       US
```

My output:

```
Querying https://api.xyz.com/v3/businesses/matches ...
True
Querying https://api.xyz.com/v3/businesses/matches ...
4.0
Querying https://api.xyz.com/v3/businesses/matches ...
$$
Querying https://api.xyz.com/v3/businesses/matches ...
Querying https://api.xyz.com/v3/businesses/matches ...
```

The real issue is my output only returns business id in the csv. and the rating etc as u see is just returned in the console. how do I set a loop such that it returns for all the businesses the info i desire into a single CSV?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your CSV file?

Comment: The CSV file has info on the name of the business along with its address,city,state,zip and country

Comment: Can you please edit your post with an example line?  We need to know how to parse the business CSV

Comment: They are seperated by a space?

Comment: This is just an example. ignore formatting. But each header has the info below in the masterdata

Comment: Is the business ID the same as the name?

Comment: What is the separator in the CSV file?  Is it actually a comma?  Is the example you posted from the raw file or from a pandas data frame?

Comment: Business ID I have already retrieved for each business

Comment: And how do you match the business ID to the business name?  For what you have asked, there is a lot of information that is missing.

Comment: I have already matched b_id with name. My question is how to merge all these outputs into one uniform csv

Comment: So if I give you a business name you can give me its id? what if `is_priced` took business_name instead of id, would that still work for you? Because we only have access to the name in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

The csv module is useful for this sort of thing e.g.

```
import csv

with open('f.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        for row in reader:
            business_id = row[0]
            row.append(get_price_index(business_id))
            row.append(get_rate_index(business_id))
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the business names from the CSV file, iterate over them using a `for` loop, hit the API and store the results, and write to a new CSV file.

```
import csv

data = []

with open('businesses.csv') as fp:
    # skip header line
    header = next(fp)
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        b_name = reader[0]
        # not sure how you get the business ID:
        b_id = get_business_id(b_name)
        p = is_priced(b_id)
        r = is_rated(b_id)
        out.append((b_name, p, r))

# write out the results
with open('business_data.csv', 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(['name', 'price', 'rating'])
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv', usecols=['business_name']) # since you only need the name
# you'll receive business_name in your functions
csv = csv.apply(is_priced, axis=1) 
csv = csv.apply(is_rated, axis=1)
csv.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

All you have to do in your functions is:

```
def is_priced(row):
    business_name = row['business_name']
    business_id = ??
    ...
```

Comment: please see reedit. The issue is i am able to run a loop but it retrieves only b_id, the other verticals like rating etc fail to come in to csv.

Comment: Oh my bad, see the eidt.